# AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'image_id'

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

I have this python code of image processing using face++ service.

mine code is:

```
import requests
import json


API_KEY = "***************************"
API_SECRET = "**************************"

detect = {
    'api_key': (None, API_KEY),
    'api_secret': (None, API_SECRET),
    'image_file': ('image_file.jpg', open('image_file.jpg', 'rb')),
    'return_attributes': (None, 'gender,age'),
}

response = requests.post('https://api-us.faceplusplus.com/facepp/v3/detect', files=detect)

responseData = (response.text)
print(responseData)
print("----------------------------------------------------")
print(responseData.image_id)
```

above give error `AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'image id'`

so when i print the image_id in the end i get this error so hope you solve it.

Answer (score 1):

You should parse the response as JSON instead:

```
responseData = response.json()
```